# how to make an Ember.js app offline with server sync when available

Tags: html, ember.js, offline, breeze

is there any library that handles this? like the [backbone.offline](https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline) one?, if not, will this be difficult to implement with Ember.js?

**UPDATE**

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005419/how-to-make-an-angular-js-app-offline-with-server-sync-when-available) has two libraries that can help, Breeze.js and Jaydata..

Comment: Ember doesn't have that feature. I might be wrong, but as I understand, the solution would be implementing an adapter and serializer for browser's `localStorage` (or something like that) and create the logic to sync once you're back on the internet.

Comment: yeah that should work, but i dont know if Ember.js has a central point for backend communication (like Backbone.js `sync` method)

Comment: I don't know if it has, as far as I know it doesn't, so you'd have to implement one. If I'm not mistaken, something *like* this is sort of planned

Comment: [this](http://petelepage.com/webapp-codelab/) has some bits that you might find useful.

Answer (score 4):

[`ember-localstorage`](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) adapter can be used.

it can be used like other adapters.

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.LSAdapter.create()
});
```

Another good library for ember and rails is [`ember-data-sync.js`](https://github.com/panayi/ember-data-sync)

Extend your App.Store from DS.SyncStore. Define the adapter you want to use for client-side storage:

```
App.Store = DS.SyncStore.extend({
      revision: 10,
      adapter: DS.IndexedDB.adapter({
        mappings: {
          person: App.Person,
          persons: App.Person,
          contact: App.Contact,
          contacts: App.Contact
        }
      })

});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no library for this, but you could implement it with a custom adapter. There isn't much documentation for the adapter API and the only ones available in core so far are [`RESTAdapter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js) and [`FixtureAdapter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js).

What you basically need to do there is implement couple of hooks and plug that into your  application's store.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a solution also, and came upon the [ember-sync](https://github.com/kurko/ember-sync) project.

This project piggy-backs on Ember-Data, is `ember-cli`-ready, and has a queuing feature that smartly handles backend record CRUD. From my brief look into it, I'd say this is the lead project for Ember.js offline-capable apps.

One critique I'd submit on this project is that it ought to also be capable of adapting with [epf.io](http://epf.io), which itself is a drop-in replacement for Ember-Data and offers transactional CRUD, nested stores -- and even per-model nested store capabilities.

At the time of writing, this project is still in alpha, though it seems to be heading in the right direction.