# how to make an Angular.js app offline with server sync when available

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, offline, breeze

I'm looking for an approach or a library that handles this. the idea is to store data in localstorage and sync to the backend when a connection is available, http://pouchdb.com/ looks like a cool solution but anyone has use it on production?

**UPDATE:**

Right now you can also use:

- [MeteorJS + Angular](https://www.meteor.com/)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
- [Parse](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)
- [Horizon](http://horizon.io)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haven't used it yet, but familiar w/ the concepts behind BreezeJS from their other offerings in .NET. Check it out http://www.breezejs.com/ and here's Ward Bell presenting it to the Googlers
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2ErSQj3SN8&feature=player_profilepage

Answer (score 2):

you can also take a look at jaydata
http://jaydata.org/blog/synchronized-online-offline-data-applications-part-2-syncing-large-tables-and-tables-with-foreign-relations

Comment: Free for open-source apps, premium for closed-source

Comment: That is not correct. Most of the library if absolutely free and open sourced with MIT license. Some advanced features are payware if used for commercial purposes but still free for non-commercial use even if the software using the lib is not open sourced. Local to remote sync can be developed without the advanced features so a commercial solution can be developed without payment.

Answer (score -1):

breezejs is not a sync solution! 
if server data changes what happen in local data
if some recordes deleted on server after last update local data must sync after a method called sync in other word some date must come back to client after calling savechange that tell client db to be sync with server

Comment: While this might be useful information, it should not be answer rather a comment.

Comment: Synch/ Distributed solutions rarely allow delete records from the server.  You use an inactive/ isdeleted field. Without that  you are forced into non scalable full table merges.